# Should I avoid modelling clothes out of a reference image?

Tags: modeling, mesh, image

I wanted to recreate my jacket, so I decided to use an image to create a mesh of it, however I want to eventually fit it onto a human body so should I have not done it this way?[image]

Comment: Easiest method for creating clothes that are going to be used on character is to use the character mesh duplicate it and scale just a bit and make clothes out of that mesh.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.